# Excel VBA: how to write out nested array into a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I've recently started playing with nested arrays in Excel. I've been having a few issues with using them.

The method I usually use to quickly write out an array to a range no longer works. The reason that fails seems to be because of the way I try to find the dimensions of the nested array (see code below). I know I could use a nested for loop to write out the array, but is there a better/faster way?

```
Sub print_arr()

Dim test_arr(1 to 10) as variant

for i = 1 to 10
    test_arr(i) = Array(1,2,3,4)
next I

'sample Locals readout: test_arr(1)(0) = 1, test_arr(1)(1) = 2, test_arr(1)(2) = 3, test_arr(1)(3) = 4,

Dim Desination as Range
Set Destination = Range("A1")
'normally I would do something like
Destination.Resize(UBound(test_arr, 1), UBound(test_arr, 2)).Value = test_arr
'but this doesn't work for a nested array
'there is an issue with the ubound(test_arr,2) 
'so what's the best way to write out nested array to Destination?

End Sub
```

What I want to see as a result of running the above code is the following in a sheet:

```
       A | B | C | D |
    ------------------
    1: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    2: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    3: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    4: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    5: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    6: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    7: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    8: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    9: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
   10: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

Another related side question: what's the best way to check if the value in test_arr(i) is a nested array? If there is a nested array, then Ubound(test_arr(i)) works and gives me the expected value of 3. If test_arr(i) is not a nested array or is empty, then ubound(test_arr(i)) produces a "type mismatch" error.

Comment: Will you actually be in a situation where you don't know if something is a 2-D array vs. an array of arrays ?  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm has a function to determine the number of dimensions for an array.  `Debug.Print TypeName(test_arr(1)) Like "*()"` will tell you if an array slot holds a nested array.

Comment: I think it's a likely situation if I want to use a nested array to fill out a table via index-matches. There's a chance that some parts of that array may be empty due to a failure of the index-match.